# Creating a SQL query in Access that shows the average date/time as a decimal number

Tags: sql, ms-access, integer, average

I have the task to create a query that will provide the average date/time, which is supposed to be a decimal number as the date/time is stored as an integer timestamp.The column in the original table consists of the date (YYYY-DD-MM) and time (HH:MM:SS). I have tried a couple of functions but they didn't work.

Tried:

```
SELECT avg(tweets.created) AS AverageDate

FROM Tweets;
```

But it says: "data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Cheers.

Comment: Excuse me for improperly posing the question, I am new to the forum. I have tried CAST(-constructs like SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(datefield AS INT)) AS DATETIME) FROM table; or SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(datefield AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) FROM table; and CONVERT(DATETIME, AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT, datefield))) as [AverageDate]. The query consists of 500 records. The error I get when I fill in these codes is "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression". So the task is basically to create an average of the date and time expressed in a decimal number.

Comment: Please update your post with attempted SQL and any errors/undesired results and not as long comments. See edit link at bottom of post below tags. Then delete this long, hard to read comment.

Comment: By the way, `CAST`, `CONVERT` is not part of the MS Access SQL dialect. Are you running SQL Server backend?